# Cannot find libgmp when compiling GCC 4.5.2

Tags: make, gcc

I'm attempting to compile GCC 4.5.2 as part of the Linux from Scratch book (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html). My configure is as follows:

```
./configure \
    --target=$LFS_TGT --prefix=/tools \
    --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib \
    --disable-decimal-float --disable-threads \
    --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp \
    --disable-libgomp --enable-languages=c \
    --with-gmp-include=$(pwd)/gmp --with-gmp-lib=$(pwd)/gmp/.libs \
    --without-ppl --without-cloog
```

When I attempt to **make** I get the error (after digging around in config.logs):

*error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I have *gmp* in a subdirectory and got to this point after successfully compiling it. How can I point GCC to use this library?

I'm going through LFS in an attempt to get myself more familiar with Linux behaviour. I've jumped over a fair few hurdles but this particular case is stumping me.

If it's relevant: I'm using an Ubuntu 11 host. Any ideas?

With thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the issue was caused by my (dumb) decision to use a combined source + build directory. Cleaning up my environment and re-building to a different folder has addressed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to GMP using the below switch, add that to your configure statement.

```
--with-gmp=$(PWD)/gmp
```

Comment: If I'm reading the configuration docs correctly --with-gmp is equivalent to --with-gmp-include and --with-gmp-lib (can't test this until the morning)

Comment: This is what ./configure --help says -- --with-gmp-include=PATH specify directory for installed GMP include files
  --with-gmp-lib=PATH     specify directory for the installed GMP library so you actually need to point to the include directory and libs directory or alternately you could just point to the parent directory with the above option

Comment: I'm already doing so, however, as indicated.

Comment: look at your config.log and see whats going wrong, may be you should post the errors from config.log here

Comment: That's where the error came from... (also, tried --with-gmp instead. No change). The file does definitely exist in the location I've specified.

Comment: The build is convinced it isn't there. There's no associated errors in the config.logs other than 'No such file or directory'.